# Grepping source code branch tips

Tags: git

How to grep all branch tips in a repo trying to find uses and definitions of a certain function?

Am afraid `git log -S` is not an option because of it grepping all history.

Comment: Author of the first answer, please do undelete..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [git grep](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep). Let's say you are searching for "myFunctionName"; simply do:

```
git branch | cut -c3- | xargs git grep 'myFunctionName'
```

This will search the tips of all branches.

Comment: That is a cool command sequence! Actually I think I was wanting `git branch -a | cut -c 3- | grep -v HEAD | xargs git grep [-i] PATTERN`. Thanks a lot!